# Limit input of regular expression validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I'm currently coding a ASP.NET web application using VB.NET. I'd like to know how to limit the input of the regular expression validator to numbers only (with specific number of digits e.g 7-20 digits).

Answer (score 4):

You can use curly brackets in regular expression to limit like this

```
^[0-9]{7,20}$
```

This will limit it from 7-20 digits. For detail explanation see this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="req" runat="server" ErrorMessage="hi" 
     ControlToValidate="txt1" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{7,20}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is an another way to allow numeric only with minimum 7 and maximum 20 characters

Comment: True, but in .NET this also matches other numerals like Arabian `٣`. Not sure if that is desired.

Comment: i think, it is not true. I checked it in regex exe as well as in .Net regular expression validation control. This character is not accepted for above mentioned expression.

Comment: Hm. According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.80).aspx), it matches the same as `\p{Nd}` which does match Arabian digits. You're talking about server-side validation? Client-side validation has to be done in JavaScript, and there `\d` indeed only matches `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thanks for knowledge sharing. I hope he is using English only. BTW my answer is updated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{7,20}$"
```